# ASPNETCORE Azure AD B2C SPA login popup is showing incorrect email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to set up Azure AD B2C identity provider framework with a ReactJS SPA and ASPNETCORE60 Web API backend. Everything works fine except the email address on the login popup as shown below:

[image]

In the bottom section where it shows something like an email, with GUID before the @, I couldn't find an object with that GUID. How to fix it to display the correct UPN?

I checked the Azure AD B2C documentation and did not find anything useful, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: The UPN you are getting is in the format of `ObjectID@xxx.onmicrosoft.com` that is the GUID is the `ObjectID` of the user and `xxx` is the tenant the user belongs to.

In my case, I got the **pop-up** like below:

[image]

Here, to find the user with the `ObjectID` with the UPN `xxx@rukb2c.onmicrosoft.com`, I checked that user belongs to `rukb2c` tenant.

Hence, when I switched to rukb2c tenant, **I am able to find the user with the `ObjectID` like below**:

*Go to the Tenant -> Users -> Search ObjectID*

[image]

**To update the UPN of the user**, you can *select the user -> click on edit -> Save*:

[image]

***The user UPN updated successfully like below:***

[image]

Now, I created an **Azure AD B2C SPA Application** like below:

[image]

To authenticate the user, I used the below endpoint:

```json
https://rukb2c.b2clogin.com/rukb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsft.com/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

The code got generated like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://rukb2c.b2clogin.com/rukb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

Comment: In my case I had the correct UPN but was still showing a wrong GUID (I did not find this ObjectID in the tenant I was testing)

Comment: Can you please attach the snips of the portal?